# How to change the style of SwipeRefreshLayout (Material design to progress bar)

Tags: android, material-design

I had my project on Eclipse, and when I implemented the SwipeRefreshLayout it was showing the progress bar style. The problem is that I recently imported my project to Android Studio, and now the SwipeRefreshLayout is like Material Design style... so ugly in my opinion..

How can I change it now?
Have I to change the compilation version?

Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to showing the progress bar, not a Material Design style, just use the elder support v4. I think you can find the links, or you can download the jar, then copy to your libs.